# Report Builder Query Text Editor Where Clause Parentheses

Tags: sql, where-clause, parentheses, reportbuilder

My employer has switched data systems and reporting tools. We used to use Report Builder with a nicely built data model that allowed me to do some complex filtering easily. Then we used Business Objects, and though I didn't like it very much, it also let me do some complex filtering. Now we're back to Report Builder, but the data model is different, and the only filtering I seem to be able to do is a string of AND operators.

(Note: I'm self-taught on both Report Builder and Business Objects. I have minimal experience with the SQL coding language itself. Also, actual data labels have been changed in this example.)

I'm pulling from a large amount of data, so I need to filter on the query level. I first need to include data based on five criteria, like this.

```
    | SYSTEM.REGION.REGION_STATUS_CODE = N'1'
    | SYSTEM.STATE.STATE_STATUS_CODE = N'1'
AND | SYSTEM.ORDERS.DISCARDED_DATE IS NULL
    | SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_DISCARDED_DATE IS NULL
    | SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_STATUS_CODE = N'01'
```

Then I need to include data that fits one of two pairings, like this.

```
   |     | SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_CONTRACT_CODE = N'Retail'
   | AND | SYSTEM.ORDERS.DISCOUNT_CODE = N'N/A'
OR | 
   |     | SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_CONTRACT_CODE = N'Wholesale'
   | AND | SYSTEM.ORDERS.DISCOUNT_CODE != N'N/A'
```

After I built my query using the query designer and switched to text mode, it gave me this.

```
WHERE
  SYSTEM.REGION.REGION_STATUS_CODE = N'1'
  AND SYSTEM.STATE.STATE_STATUS_CODE = N'1'
  AND SYSTEM.ORDERS.DISCARDED_DATE IS NULL
  AND SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_DISCARDED_DATE IS NULL
  AND SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_STATUS_CODE = N'01'
  AND SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_CONTRACT_CODE = N'Retail'
  AND SYSTEM.ORDERS.DISCOUNT_CODE = N'N/A'
  AND SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_CONTRACT_CODE = N'Wholesale'
  AND SYSTEM.ORDERS.DISCOUNT_CODE != N'N/A'
```

I've tried putting parentheses in, but I must have done it wrong because the query ran for ages before essentially giving me the entire database.

Anybody care to help a SQL newbie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming everything else is right, it should just be about applying parenthesis to get the logic right. Using slightly exaggerated whitespace to try and make it clear:

```
WHERE
  SYSTEM.REGION.REGION_STATUS_CODE = N'1'
  AND SYSTEM.STATE.STATE_STATUS_CODE = N'1'
  AND SYSTEM.ORDERS.DISCARDED_DATE IS NULL
  AND SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_DISCARDED_DATE IS NULL
  AND SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_STATUS_CODE = N'01'
  AND (
        (SYSTEM.ORDERS.DISCOUNT_CODE = N'N/A'
         AND SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_CONTRACT_CODE = N'Retail')
       OR
        (SYSTEM.ORDERS.DISCOUNT_CODE != N'N/A'
         AND SYSTEM.SERVICE.SERVICE_CONTRACT_CODE = N'Wholesale')
      )
```

(It still may run forever, but that's more a factor of database size and indexing.)

Comment: Spot on! Not only does the report work just as I hoped it would now (and fairly quickly at that), but I think I can also use this to figure out other complex filtering on future reports. Thank you!